# Is it possible to fit Non-Stationary GEV to a series of data in R fixing one of the distribution parameters?

Tags: r, distribution, curve-fitting

Good afternoon,

I have a series of annual maxima data (say "AMdata") I'd like to model through a non-stationary GEV distribution. In particular, I want the location to vary linearly in time, i.e.:
mu = mu0 + mu1*t.

To this end, I am using the ismev package in R, computing the parameters as follows:

```
require(ismev)
ydat = cbind(1:length(AMdata)) ### Co-variates - years from 1 to number of annual maxima in the data
GEV_fit_1_loc = gev.fit(xdat=AMdata,ydat=ydat,mul=1)
```

In such a way, I obtain 4 parameters, namely mu0,mu1,shape and scale.

My question is: can I apply the gev.fit function fixing as a condition the value of mu1? not as a starting value for the successive iterations, but as a given parameter (thus estimating the three parameters left)?

Any tip would be really appreciated!

Francesco

Comment: This really sounds like a data modeling question rather than a specific programming question. This may be a better fit for [stats.se] instead of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will ask on that platform then.